# Поиск количества общих подпоследовательностей заданной длины (Описание ниже)

Tags: java, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Пусть есть два массива чисел (последовательности) размерности *n* и *m* (*1 <= n, m <= 40*). Также дано некое число *k*.

Необходимо найти количество общих подпоследовательностей в двух массивах длины *k*, где *1 < k <= min(n, m)*.

Интересует *алгоритмически эффективный способ без переборов* (возможно некая модификация алгоритма поиска наибольшей общей подпоследовательности), потому что нужно использовать на больших массивах. Спасибо.

Comment: Какие ограничения на n,m? Раз вы знаете про LCS, то алгоритм с кубический памятью должны представлять.

Comment: @MBo, 1 <= n, m <= 40. Пардон, но про алгоритм с кубической памятью не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Делаете массив размером NxM, как для LCS, но каждая ячейка содержит не одно число, а массив, список, или словарь, в котором хранятся количества общих подпоследовательностей, заканчивающихся в i/j элементах, и имеющих длины от 1 до k.

Comment: Можете попробовать кодом описать алгоритм? А то, как по мне, звучит довольно вычурно.

Comment: Ну я не писал, только из головы - думаю, что так должно быть. Если будет время проверить - набросаю псевдокод.

Comment: @demmen Написал на Python  - количество всех подпоследовательностей верно считает, а вот с определённой длиной я что-то не могу пока вычленить. [Вот на этом коде](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-common-subsequence-in-two-strings/) основывался, только по длинам разбивал `if (s[i - 1] == t[j - 1]):                for u in range(1, nn+1):                    dp[i][j][u] = (1 + dp[i][j - 1][u-1] +  dp[i - 1][j][u-1])            else:                for u in range(1, nn+1):                    dp[i][j][u] = (dp[i][j - 1][u] + dp[i - 1][j][u] -  dp[i - 1][j - 1][u])`